# Page/Tab effectiveness on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Does anyone know how to determine how many people click the LIKE button on a specific tab in Facebook?  We've created new Tab (new iframe tabs), and would like to determine how effective they are at getting people to Like us.  So, if we have a free offer tab and an About Us tab, and each of those has the Facebook like button on it (standard FB like button), how can we determine how many Liked us from that tab (to know if the tab is effective or not)?

Answer (score 0):

should work if you extend the like url with an ref param. e.g.

`?ref=about`

see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397/ for more information.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the Like buttons on Facebook.  I already track the like buttons on my site.  Facebook allows different/custom tabs, and the like button is at the top of those pages.  Trying to determine which tabs work best.